# Can't parse \ in strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, split, indexof

I'm setting up some processes to automate a variety of string modifications. All's going well, until I want to do ANYTHING with "\"

For instance:

var foo = "Continent\Country\State\County\Town"

But I get errors if I do things like:
foo.indexOf("\")
foo.split("\")

I get an error of "unterminated string literal"

Any idea what I can do to index or split on "\"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `foo.indexOf("\\");  foo.split("\\");`

You may have to change your string to in order to escape the \ to something like the following:

```
var foo = "Continent\\Country\\State\\County\\Town"
```

Comment: Not a problem, I am glad I could help.

Comment: @dmperkins74 You might check out my update if you are wanting to split your string into an array.

Answer (score 2):

Backslash is the character that indicates an escape. It it used for things like `\n` (newline) `\t` (tab) and several others.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp (scroll down to escape character)

In your case, you are indicating that you are about to escape a character by using `\`, but then the next character is `"`, which indicates that you wanted to escape the double quotes. `Continent\Country` indicates that you are trying to escape the `C` character.

The fix, as indicated by others here, is to escape the backslash by using `\\`.

```
var foo = "Continent\\Country\\State\\County\\Town"
foo.indexOf("\\") 
foo.split("\\")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var pattern = /\\/;
result = str.split( pattern );
```